# Return variable from function to an input variable

Tags: java, android

How to change variable by calling function?

Example

```
byte a;
...

void setBit(byte variable, byte n){
variable |= (1<<n);

}

...
setBit(a,2);

System.out.println(a); // expected output "2"
```

I could write `a = setBit(a,2);` but thats not what i need

As example from Arduino

```
#define bitRead(value, bit) (((value) >> (bit)) & 0x01)
#define bitSet(value, bit) ((value) |= (1UL << (bit)))
#define bitClear(value, bit) ((value) &= ~(1UL << (bit)))
#define bitWrite(value, bit, bitvalue) (bitvalue ? bitSet(value, bit) : bitClear(value, bit))
```

Comment: That's not how Java works. Best you can do is change the property of an object.

Comment: You can't modify the callers value held by the variable of a primitive type. You'll need to return the modified `byte` and assign it to something in the caller. Or, use an array or object.

Answer (score 2):

You could use return from your setter method like:

```
private byte setBit(byte variable, byte n){
     variable |= (1<<n);
     return variable;
}
```

And modify caller code as:

```
a = setBit(a, 2);
```

Comment: As i wrote in question i want to prevent this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, it cannot be done unless you make your own ByteWrapper which would allow modification of it's internals.

you cannot pass basic types by reference like in c++.
This is a good thing in a lot of circumstances and a thing to be missed under some specialized circumstances.

Similar to what Venkatesh tried to suggest, but different in that it doesn't use the Byte (which is immutable afaik) object you can implement the ByteWrapper , but it won't auto-cast to byte basic type like Byte. you'll have to call byteWrapper.getByte();

```
public class ByteWrapper {
    private byte byteValue = 0;
    public ByteWrapper(byte b) {
        byteValue = b;
    }

    public byte getByte() { return b; }
    public void setByte(byte b) { byteValue = b; }
}
```

then you can use

```
void setBit(ByteWrapper bw, byte n){
    bw.setByte(byte.getByte() |= (1<<n));
}
```

However, +1'ing almas shaikh's answer as that's the way to go in this case. much simpler and therefor more elegant.